# How can I add dark shading to an outer div but not inner div with css?

Tags: css, overlay, background-color, webcam, camera-overlay

I am positioning an overlay on a webcam in my react app to show a user where to position their face. Here is my JSX:

```
<div className='webcam-container'>
    <Webcam
        ref={webcamRef}
        screenshotFormat='image/jpeg'
        screenshotQuality={1}
        width={360}
    />
    <div className='webcam-overlay'>
        <div className='face-position-indicator' />
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my css:

```
.webcam-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 360px;
    height: 270px;
}

.webcam-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.face-position-indicator {
    width: 150px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5%;
    left: 10%;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

It looks fine but I would like the background outside the `<div className='face-position-indicator' />` to be shaded dark, so my question is how can I add a shading only to the `div` with a class of `webcam-overlay` but not the inner `div` with a class of `face-position-indicator`?

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
.webcam-overlay {
    ...
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}

.face-position-indicator {
    ...
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

and:

```
.webcam-overlay {
    ...
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}

.face-position-indicator {
    ...
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

However both these attempts just give a dark shading to all the elements.

Interestingly if I do:

```
.webcam-overlay {
    ...
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.face-position-indicator {
    ...
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}
```

I get a light background on the outer div and a dark background on the inner div. But I can't achieve the opposite effect which is what I need.

Am I missing something? Is there some kind of css trick I need to apply? Chat GPT suggested adding a pseudo-element to my `webcam-overlay` but this also just made everything dark.

Comment: did you try a big box-shadow with na overflow hidden?

Comment: Could you please provide an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:  A more complicated but more flexible way to do this with SVG masks.  I will say that I am not certain this is the best way to do this, though, but it definitely works.

```css
.container{
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.overlay{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1611915387288-fd8d2f5f928b?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxleHBsb3JlLWZlZWR8Mnx8fGVufDB8fHx8&w=1000&q=80" height="100%" width="100%">
  <div class="overlay">
     <svg height="100%" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
     <defs>
        <mask id="mask" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
          <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="rgb(255, 255, 255)"></rect>
          <circle cx="25" cy="35" r="20"></circle>
        </mask>
      </defs>
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#mask)"  fill="rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)" ></rect>
     </svg>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

END EDIT

You can use an inset box-shadow with partial transparency:

```css
.container{
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}


.overlay{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1611915387288-fd8d2f5f928b?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxleHBsb3JlLWZlZWR8Mnx8fGVufDB8fHx8&w=1000&q=80" height="100%" width="100%">
  <div class="overlay">
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting. Is it possible to apply this to a curved shape that is positioned off-center though?

Comment: Hmmm maybe, maybe not, depends on the exact needs.  Can you update your question with a more detailed description of what you need?

Comment: My `<div className='face-position-indicator' />` is an oval shape positioned towards the top left of `<div className='webcam-overlay'>`. This is the element I would like to have light while the rest of `<div className='webcam-overlay'>` appears shaded

Comment: Added a flexible SVG solution, mostly stolen from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61991739/why-is-my-svg-mask-partially-transparent)

Comment: Works great! I just changed `<circle cx="25" cy="35" r="20"></circle>` to `<ellipse cx='110' cy='115' rx='75' ry='100'></ellipse>` to suit my specific needs. Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

You can try like below:

```css
.container{
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden; /** don't forget this */
}

.container:before{
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  top: 50px;
  left:50px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 100vmax #0009; /* a big box-shadow will do the trick*/ 
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1611915387288-fd8d2f5f928b?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxleHBsb3JlLWZlZWR8Mnx8fGVufDB8fHx8&w=1000&q=80"">
</div>
```